# IE9 breaks jquery and fancybox

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9, fancybox

I have a problem with the IE9; it doesn't open `fancybox`. I get 2 errors (translated):

> **SCRIPT5: Access denied**
>
> jquery.min.js?1345532875, Row 2 char 68522

and:

> **SCRIPT5007: There is no value for the propert "trigger": The object is null or undefined**
>
> jquery.fancybox.pack.js?1342011870, Row 28 char 117

Hope someone knows a solution.

Comment: You should add code too . Are you making any cross domain requests ?

Comment: First error sounds like a cross-domain issue, for example the fancybox is pointing to a different server or different protocol on same server, and that frame is trying to access something on the parent frame.   As others have indicated, this is really very hard to diagnose without code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my code:

```
<script src="fileadmin/templates/js/libs/jquery.min.js?1345532875" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="fileadmin/templates/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?1342011870" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.fblang').fancybox({
      padding: 0,
      openEffect : 'elastic',
      openSpeed  : 150,
      closeEffect : 'elastic',
      closeSpeed  : 150,
      helpers : {
        overlay:{ opacity : 0.3 }
      }
    });
});
</script>
```

The jQuery Version is 1.8.0 and fancybox 2.0.6. The whole thing is running in a Typo3 CMS ( if that is important)

**EDIT:** I got it working. I just include the external jquery file from https://ajax.googleapis.com

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

In order to help you, we need not only the error messages you have, but your code. With just the errors, it's a hard guess.

Can you please post the JavaScript of the web page in which you are trying to use Fancybox?
Also, please show us which js libraries you are including.

Comment: this should be a comment, not an answer (welcome to stackoverflow)

Comment: Thing is – when your rep is low 'cause you're new, you aren't allowed to comment except on your own posts.